# How to integrate a logsumexp function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to integrate a logsumexp function which is a smooth function of another piecewise function.

Run

`Integrate[ Log[Exp[s*a] + Exp[s*(a + v +a*t)]], {t, 0, (-v +vm)/a}, Assumptions -> {s > 0, a > 0, v >= 0, vm > 0}]`,

then, I got

`(PolyLog[2, -e^(v * s)] - PolyLog[2, -e^(vm * s])] + a (-v + vm)*s^2)/(a*s)`.

But if I run

`Integrate[ Log[Exp[s*a] + Exp[s*(a + v +a*t + (v +a*t)^2)]], {t, 0, (-v +vm)/a}, Assumptions -> {s > 0, a > 0, v >= 0, vm > 0}]`,

I cannot get any result.

Comment: Are you aware that there might be integrals out there that cannot be expressed in closed form?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Maybe you are right. If that is true, do you have any suggestion to solve this? numerical interation?

Comment: If you replace the free variables (`s`, `a`m `v`, `vm`, ...) by numeric values then you can apply numeric integration by using `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate`.

Comment: Amplifying on Henrik's comment: See the tutorial on  [`Integration`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Integration.html), specificly the example `Integrate[x^x, x]` for which it is stated "This integral simply cannot be done in terms of standard mathematical functions. As a result, the Wolfram Language just leaves it undone. "